# Fix motorcycle(FZ-S) accelerator

Tags: yamaha

I own a Yamaha FZ-S V2 which is available in India only I guess. It is 17 months old and now the accelerator is not working properly, the engine shuts down after I start and then pull the accelerator slowly. I can manage not shutting down by pulling it very quickly which makes the engine to moan!

Could you please tell me what the problem could be and how it can be solved.

Comment: Being 17 months old, it should still be under warranty. If all the common things like gas, air filter, etc. are alright, I'd suggest you take it back to the dealership.

Comment: Unfortunately i was informed that its not covered under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Check the air filter and fuel filter. Also check the float in the carburetors to make sure they're working properly.  The needle valve might be sticking or the floats might be out of adjustment.